# Problemas com distinção de session quando duas pessoas logão com o mesmo usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com um problema de Session em um projeto onde uso C# e ASP.NET. Se duas pessoas logarem ao mesmo tempo com o mesmo usuário as variáveis de seção ficam com os mesmo valores. Para ter certeza eu peguei o ID das seções criadas e eles são diferenças, portanto, não consigo fazer com que um valor de uma seção não interfira na outra.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Pode a cada vez que logar gerar um novo token para a sessão, se uma requisição vier com um token diferente do atual, você direciona para a página de login.

Comment: Poderia compartilhar um pedaço do código para que possamos tentar ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um id utilizando o ip da maquina ou até mesmo informações de identificação do browser, podendo transformar essas informações em um único MD5 para cada conexão.